# Running Django on Apache Behind nginx - What Apache optimizations can I make

Tags: django, apache, nginx, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-11.04

I have a configured and running setup that I am looking to optimize. I do not want to swap out Apache for gunicorn or other options at this stage.

My setup is so:

Ubuntu 11.04
Default nginx from apt-get
Default apache from apt-get

Nginx serves static files, and passes application requests through to Apache. Apache will have between 5-8 Django projects (ie - distinct websites). Small to medium traffic. Apache only has django projects (served via mod_wsgi) - I don't need php or anything that Django does not need.

From the default Ubuntu/Apache, what mods can I disable, and are there any other configuration tweaks I can do to more optimally use resources on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

One configuration tweak is that, if you don't need apache to serve anything else than django sites, ditch apache completely.

Use a dedicated WSGI server like uwsgi ( http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/ ) or gunicorn ( http://gunicorn.org/ ). They are well documented and **so** low on resource usage.

Comment: With a dedicated WSGI server you can also better balance the machine availability, in that you assign a specific number of workers to each app, so no single app could take down the others in case of a DOS.

Comment: You can also restart each of the apps separately, and raise/lower the worker availability with OS signals (with gunicorn, you send TTIN or TTOU respectively)

Comment: The question states that I don't want to replace apache with gunicorn or a different wsgi server. I am after more, specific tips on getting apache optimal for my scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that sentence :(. When I switched my django massive site system (30+ sites, 450 workers, ~900 reqs per second on a signle machine) from apache to gunicorn it was a bless. If at any time you think about switching, why not now?

Comment: Daemon mode of mod_wsgi allows you for each site to specifify easily a different number of processes and threads. Daemon mode also allows you to restart a site easily by touching the WSGI file. You could also use signals to do the restart but there is no means of increasing/reducing the number of processes. There are convoluted means you could achieve the same thing by using standby processes and mapping a site to additional processes, but generally is not worth the trouble and you are better off changing the configuration properly.

Comment: OP should also be congratulated on actually seeking out help on how to get Apache to run efficiently. In various cases where I have heard people migrate to alternatives and got better results, have found there Apache configuration was broken enough that it wasn't surprising. It is unfortunate that the default Apache configuration is more setup for static files and PHP. So, run with the defaults for Python and it obviously isn't going to run as good as it could. In terms of getting advice, the mod_wsgi list is probably a better place. Stackoverflow is not a forum and discussing it here is hard.

Comment: Ok Graham, I'll try the mod_wsgi list too. I have used your site before as reference (I touch django.wsgi to reload code, picked that up from your site I think), but I guess I am looking here for answers like: use Daemon mode (I am), disable mod x, y, and z. Change config X inside Apache conf file - some general "best practices". that would approximately suit my use case.

Comment: Discussion thread on mod_wsgi list is 'http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/edffb22b2eac134b'. Will try and go into it quite deep and then put it altogether as documentation this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WSGIOptimize](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonOptimize) option to make all your .py files into .pyo. You can also use [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#memcached) to enable cache. [This](http://gregbrown.co.nz/code/optimising-django-apache-and-mod_wsgi-for-a-lightweight-ubuntu-vps/) blog describes how to run several django sites in one daemon. It is said to be useful in case where you need to serve a lot of sites, each with low traffic. [This](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-performance-tips/) contains tips from Jacob Kaplan-Moss.

Comment: The blog link is useful, thanks. Jacob's post is a bit old, but still some useful stuff.

Comment: WSGIOptimize will actually make very little difference and could actually be dangerous as it can strip doc strings out of programs which something may rely on. Part of the reason it makes no difference is that the optimisations apply in part only to startup, but mod_wsgi processes would be persistent in memory if set up in a sane way. So doesn't do anything beyond the initial startup of the process.